# Use a generic for propName in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, enums

I can use an enum as a propName for an object-like type

```
export enum WeaponClass {
    smallLaser = "smallLaser",
}

export type WeaponType = {
    [propName in WeaponClass]: number
};

const weapons: WeaponType = {
    [WeaponClass.smallLaser]: 1,
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwOrAIaUQYQBtsBnEuAbwCg5a4TVtDCAZU4KOAXjgCIGmrdlF4AaKgF8qVUJFhwYATzDBMOPABVlqntTpwA2mCgQwAOWypVAS0RrcEAsTIBdAFxwUqAEYdJAbmkAY0cSeAB3dVCPLAdELRVuSho6A1i8IlISADoBZjYSDnc4AEZxCUCgA)

Is it possible to use a generic for the propName & pass in an enum? (This throw errors)

```
export enum WeaponClass {
    smallLaser = "smallLaser",
}

export type WeaponType<T> = {
    [propName in T]: number
};

const weapons: WeaponType<WeaponClass> = {
    [WeaponClass.smallLaser]: 1,
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwOrAIaUQYQBtsBnEuAbwCg5a4TVtDCAZU4KOAXjgCIGmrdlF4AaKgF8qVUJFhwYATzDBMOPABVlwADwaAfN0o06AbTBQIYAHLZUqgJaI4GgLoAuOClQAjDpIBuaQBjCEQSeAB3dTCSTyxcMK0VHQS8IlISQx5qOjhTNLCMsgA6AWY2Eg4POABGcQkgoA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) can only iterate over type which can be property key. And exactly it is union - `string | number | symbol`. If you don't narrow the kind of `T` typescript cannot use it as a key. It means we need to perform type narrowing to only subset of types which can be used as property keys.

Fortunately there is a type which exactly represent the need - `PropertyKey`. So the whole change is to say:

```
T extends PropertyKey
```

Answer (score 0):

The error it shows it because T can be any type, but keys have restrictions on which types they can be. The solution to that would be to place a condition on the type `T` to have to extend one of those:

```
export type WeaponType<T extends (string | number | symbol)> = {
    [propName in T]: number
};
```

Comment: `string | number | symbol => PropertyKey`